# Visual Studio 2013 crashing when trying to add View MVC

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash

Everytime I try to create a view from my shoppingcart controller index ActionResult method Visual Stuido 2013 says it is not responding and closes and restarts. When I build my solution nothing is wrong, and it gives me no other error. Has anyone run into this problem and have you been able to fix it?